# Apache module FORM handling in C

Tags: c, forms, apache, apache2

I'm implementing an Apache 2.0.x module in C, to interface with an existing product we have. I need to handle FORM data, most likely using POST but I want to handle the GET case as well.

Nick Kew's [Apache Modules](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132409674) book has a section on handling form data. It provides code examples for POST and GET, which return an apr_hash_t of the key+value pairs in the form. parse_form_from_POST marshalls the bucket brigade and flattens it into a buffer, while parse_form_from_GET can simply reference the URL. Both routines rely on a parse_form_from_string routine to walk through each delimited field and extract the information into the hash table.

That would be fine, but it seems like there should be an easier way to do this than adding a couple hundred lines of code to my module. Is there an existing module or routines within apache, apr, or apr-util to extract the field names and associated data from a GET or POST FORM into a structure which C code can more easily access? I cannot find anything relevant, but this seems like a common need for which there should be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I switched to G-WAN which offers a transparent ANSI C scripts interface for GET and POST forms (and many other goodies like charts, GIF I/O, etc.).

A couple of AJAX examples are available at the [GWAN developer page](http://gwan.com/developers)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't think this reply addresses the OP's question about writing Apache modules in C, where the version of Apache predates the introduction of the ap_parse_form_data() function. (see ap_mmn.h 20110203.2 2.3.11-dev)

Answer (score 0):

While, on it's surface, this may seem common, cgi-style content handlers in C on apache are pretty rare.  Most people just use CGI, FastCGI, or the myriad of frameworks such as mod_perl.

Most of the C apache modules that I've written are targeted at modifying the particular behavior of the web server in specific, targeted ways that are applicable to every request.

If it's at all possible to write your handler outside of an apache module, I would encourage you to pursue that strategy.

Comment: This is the exact opposite of an answer! Why shouldn't we be looking for easy ways to write Apache modules that do form processing in C?

Comment: Writing form processing code in C on Apache is like writing userspace applications as kernel modules.  It's hard because nobody is doing it, and it wasn't really intended for this purpose.

Comment: I know this question is pretty old, but now in 2012 it's possible to do form parsing using Apache API functions, so I think the idea that an Apache module shouldn't do form parsing is outmoded. The idea of writing content handlers as Apache modules is perhaps uncommon, but there may be cases where it makes the most sense. In any case, if the sample from the book is adequate for the task, then the answer isn't "don't do this" it's "yep, that's the easiest way to do this".

Comment: Fair enough.  So while there is an answer on how to do it, I still would recommend against it, as somebody with a few accepted patches to the project.  If you want to get down and dirty in C it's probably for speed, in which case a lighter web server like nginx is a better approach.

Comment: I know in my case the desire to get into C is probably more like "mental illness" than anything else. ;)

Thanks for mentioning nginx. Intriguing alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet tried any solution, since I found this SO question as a result of my own frustration with the example in the "Apache Modules" book as well. But here's what I've found, so far. I will update this answer when I have researched more.

Luckily it looks like this is now a solved problem in Apache 2.4 using the [`ap_parse_form_data`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__APACHE__CORE__DAEMON.html#ga9d426b6382b49754d4f87c55f65af202) funciton.

No idea how well this works compared to your example, but here is a [much more concise `read_post` function](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/apache_mod/139.htm).

It is also possible that [`mod_form`](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_form/) could be of value.